# Error in Jasper Report

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jasper-reports

I am using jasper report to generate pdf file from my database.

Here is my code..

ReportGenerator.java

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;

public class ReportGenerator {

Connection conn;

public void generateReport() {

try {
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:SID","username","password");
System.out.println("Loading Report Designs");
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("jrxml/EmployeeReport.jrxml"));
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("ReportTitle", "PDF JasperReport");

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,conn);

//Exporting the report
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("report/EmployeeReport.pdf"));

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);

System.out.println("Report Generation Complete");
conn.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JRException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new ReportGenerator().generateReport();
}
}
```

EmployeeReport.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
"jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport name="EmployeeReport_Demo">
<queryString>
<![CDATA[select First_Name, Last_Name from employee e]]>
</queryString>
<field name="First_Name" />
<field name="Last_Name" />
<title>
<band height="50">
<staticText>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="15"/>
<textElement/>
<text><![CDATA[Jasper Report - Demo]]></text>
</staticText>
</band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
<band height="30">
<staticText>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
<textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom" />
<text>
<![CDATA[First Name: ]]>
</text>
</staticText>
<staticText>
<reportElement x="140" y="0" width="79" height="24" />
<text>
<![CDATA[Last Name: ]]>
</text>
</staticText>
</band>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
<band height="30">
<textField>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
<textFieldExpression>
<![CDATA[$F{First_Name}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="140" y="0" width="69" height="24" />
<textFieldExpression>
<![CDATA[$F{Last_Name}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
</textField>
</band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I am using this list of jar files..

```
commons-beanutils-1.7.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-lang-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
iText-1.3.jar
jasperreports-1.0.3.jar
ojdbc14.jar
```

I am getting this error in my console..

```
Loading Report Designs
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\dineshkumar.s\Documents\Eclipse Projects\EmployeeReport\jasperreport.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:236)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:223)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:211)
    at com.satyamsoft.ReportGenerator.generateReport(ReportGenerator.java:38)
    at com.satyamsoft.ReportGenerator.main(ReportGenerator.java:68)

NESTED BY :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\dineshkumar.s\Documents\Eclipse Projects\EmployeeReport\jasperreport.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:236)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:223)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:211)
    at com.satyamsoft.ReportGenerator.generateReport(ReportGenerator.java:38)
    at com.satyamsoft.ReportGenerator.main(ReportGenerator.java:68)

NESTED BY :
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: C:\Users\dineshkumar.s\Documents\Eclipse Projects\EmployeeReport\jasperreport.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:244)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:223)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:211)
    at com.satyamsoft.ReportGenerator.generateReport(ReportGenerator.java:38)
    at com.satyamsoft.ReportGenerator.main(ReportGenerator.java:68)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\dineshkumar.s\Documents\Eclipse Projects\EmployeeReport\jasperreport.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:236)
    ... 4 more
```

I have added jasperreport.dtd file in my project.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Added where? Is it at `C:\Users\dineshkumar.s\Documents\Eclipse Projects\EmployeeReport\jasperreport.dtd` which is where the code is looking?

Comment: I use iReport to edit the .jrxml files and it doesn't add the <!DOCTYPE tag, have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();

InputStream reportName = new FileInputStream(newFile(
            loader.getResource("reportes/ReporteCalendarizado.jrxml").getFile()));
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportName);
```

Comment: What's the `newFile()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes errors are caused because of spaces in paths, so if you check manually that the jasperreport.dtd file exists in the mentioned path then try to use an eclipse workspace without spaces in it (i.e. change **Eclipse Projects** to **EclipseProjects**)